# I can't download repository from github with pull. Local directory still empty

Tags: git, github

I want download github repo to local directory
I have problem with downloading repository from github.
I will tell you what i'm doing step by step :

1. Create new local directory `mkdir App`
2. Go to local directory `cd App`
3. Add remote repository `git remote add vegan https://github.com/user/repo.git`
4. Use pull for download data `git pull vegan`
5. It isn't downloading data so I used checkout to change branch on Develop`git checkout Develop`
6. And trying pull `git pull`

In output I see how files downloading or smth and display on the end

```
Already on 'Develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Develop'.
```

But after this my local directory is empty .

Comment: Your commands should fail since 1) you add a remote to an unitialised local repo 2) you try to pull a remote name instead of a branch. The only reason I see for not having a complete failure is that you created the 'App' repo in a path already containing a configured git repo. Look at the answers below and try to clone your repo properly to start with.

Comment: thank you all very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process should be the following...

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

OR

```
mkdir App
cd App
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git remote update
```

Then

```
git checkout -b Develop origin/Develop
```

`git checkout Develop` only creates a local branch called Develop.